# Allow background-image : with embedded data in html purifier

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I'm new to html purifier and I'm trying to configure this  library according to my needs.

So I have got this html source :

```
<div style="background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAAA8CAYAAABIFuztAAA....);">Text</div>
```

My config is :

```
$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array('http' => true, 'https' => true, 'mailto' => true, 'ftp' => true, 'nntp' => true, 'news' => true, 'data' => true));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bug in HTML purifier lib fixed in the next's versions.
https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/commit/5070404376d3b4287ce5c6bfae13e888b464742d